# How to use awk to edit multiple columns of csv-file

Tags: shell, csv, awk

I would like to use awk to edit a .csv-file with different type of values, for example round all values of several distinct columns to the second decimal place. The other rows may contain float-values as well, but those shall be handled in a different way.

Assuming one row looks like the one below and I would like to edit the 7th, 8th, and 9th column (in fact they are much longer, but all relevant type of values are in this example, so it's just a matter of scale):

```
L ,P_005 ,250.092 ,20.0 ,-0.80 ,0.803443 ,0.23342 ,0.83728329 ,0.0 ,0.0
```

The output should be

```
L ,P_005 , 250.092, 20.0, -0.80, 0.80, 0.23, 0.84, 0.0, E2=0.0
```

Up to now I've always round the value of one column "x" using:

```
#/bin/sh
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS = ","
file=$1
...
awk '{printf "%.2f",$x}' $1
...   
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

So how do I adapt this concept in a way, where I can

- edit multiple columns and
- display the entire csv-file

without writing down each column with a specific option?

Comment: [edit] your question to contain a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output. Use the `{}` editor button for your script, input, and output. What you have shown as the script you currently use is not valid awk syntax - please don't show us one thing and tell us it's something else as that just obfuscates your question and makes it harder for us to help you.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I hope my edits suit the requirements

Comment: When you post 1 line of sample input/output you're likely to get a solution that will only work for that 1 line of input. The more effort you put into asking your question (e.g. include any rainy day and/or edge cases you could envision occuring in your input) the more likely you are to get a robust solution.

Answer (score 2):

If I got your guestion right:

```
awk -F\; -v OFS=\; '
function foo(str) {
  if(match(str, /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/, arr)) {
    gsub(/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/, sprintf("%.2f",arr[0]), str)
  } 
  return str
} 
{
  for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
    printf "%s%s", foo($i),(i<NF?OFS:ORS)
}' test.in
```

It produced:

```
L;P_005;X 250; Y 20; Z 0; A 0.80; B 0.23; C 0.84; E1=0.00; E2=0.00 ,
```

.

Comment: if you change `+` to `{2,}` in the regex, you'll get the desired output format  `L;P_005;X 250; Y 20; Z 0; A 0.803443; B 0.23342; C 0.83728329; E1=0.0; E2=0.0 ,`

Comment: You should mention that only works for GNU awk due to the 3rd arg for match(). More importantly, this is a good example of a script that will work for the posted sample input but will fail for other potential inputs. Try changing `P_005` to `P_00.5` for example and you'll find it gets output as `P_0.50`.